# The execution of logic is not getting inside the useEffect Hook in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am making an axios API call inside an `useEffect` block with empty dependency array, but the code is not getting executed when the component is getting rendered.

If I am clicking any button then the API call is happening through `onClick` event.

I have some Date Pickers which are reflected through states, but whenever I am changing the date the state is not getting updated.

The Date Pickers are imported from [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker)

```js
const [customerStartDate, setCustomerStartDate] = useState(new Date()) ;
  const [customerEndDate, setCustomerEndDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [customerReportData, setCustomerReportData] = useState({});
  let reportData = customerReportData ;

  const handleCustomerFromDateChange = (date) => {
    setCustomerStartDate(date);
  };
  const handleCustomerToDateChange = (date) => {
    setCustomerEndDate(date);
  };

//Other code is here, not related to this question
//...

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async() => {
      const reqBody = {
        startingDcDate: customerStartDate,
        endingDcDate: customerEndDate,
      };
  
      if (isCustomerSelected) {
        reqBody.customer = selectedCustomerData?._id;
      }
      if (isDCSelected) {
        reqBody.dc = selectedDCData?.dc;
      }
  
      console.log('entered');
      const { data } = await axios.post(`/some/api/route`, reqBody) ;
      setCustomerReportData(data) ;
      console.log(data) ;
    }
    fetchData() ;
  }, [
    customerStartDate,
    customerEndDate,
    isCustomerSelected,
    selectedCustomerData,
    isDCSelected,
    selectedDCData,
  ]);

//Other code is here, not related to this question
//...
```

Comment: You are calling fetchData() again inside useEffect after declaring the function fetchData(), also you have given parameters which are checked for change and calls useEffect, so it goes into an infinite loop. Remove the last line fetchData();